# using variables in underscore.js _.where

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

is it possible to use variables with .where in _.js?

I am making a filtering system that gets an array of objects and filters out the selected objects on click. However, the objects to be filtered are different based on the elements chosen, so I would like to use _.js to filter variables passed to it with _.where

Hardcoded values work perfectly, but when replaced with replica variables, it shoots out a blank array.

```
var user_filters = user_array;
var filtered_text;
$('.allFilters li').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var selected_filter = $this.siblings('a').text();
    selected_filter = selected_filter.toLowerCase();
    var filters = $this.attr('data-filter-value');
    filters = '"'+filters+'"';
    selected_filter = selected_filter;
    console.log(selected_filter, filters);
    user_filters = _.where(user_filters, {selected_filter: filters});
    console.log (user_filters);
});
```

Comment: I think you don't need `filters = '"'+filters+'"';`. Additional can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I agree with @Satpal. That line of code is adding literal quotes to the value of `filters`, and might be causing trouble. I doubt this method is not working because you're using variables.

Comment: I am working on the fiddle now, but if I remove {selected_filter: filters} and replace it with, say, {test: "1"} it works perfectly. I have tried removing the quotes as well from the variable. Still a null unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it took me a bit to think about how to present this in a very simplistic manner.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3u6LX/

Comment: @Dreamlines with your fiddle, try and think about how the JS interpreter would know that `test` is a literal, but `selected` isn't. The notation is exactly the same. If you're going to say *because `selected` is a variable*, how would you then be able to use the literal string `selected` as a key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to use variables when calling **where**, which is to create an object literal which **where** expects. This can be done using the underscore function [_.object](http://underscorejs.org/#object) which can take either an array of keys and an array of values or an array of key value pairs.

In your example you could have done:

```
user_filters = _.where(user_filters, _.object([[selectedFilter, filters]]));
```

Comment: Wasn't 100% sure from the question whether there could be more than one selectedFilter and filters. The proposed solution assumes one but could be easily converted to work with many.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
user_filters = user_filters.filter(function(item) {
  return item[selected_filter] === filters;
});
```

(and leave out the `filters = '"'+filters+'"';` line)

Or, using Underscore's [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
user_filters = _.filter(user_filters, function(item) {
  return item[selected_filter] === filters;
});
```

Comment: This did the trick, but still leaves me wondering about what was going wrong with the original method.

edited to say Thanks so much!

Comment: @Dreamlines you cannot create a 'dynamic' object literal, where the 'key' part (the part before the `:`) is based on a variable (which is basically what you're trying to do). You have to use a more elaborate way: `var obj = {}; obj[variable] = value;`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense! Thank you so much for the great explanation and taking the time to write it out!

Answer (score 0):

Variables can be used if surrounded them by square brackets:

In your case you can do this:

```
var selected_filter = $this.siblings('a').text();
    selected_filter = selected_filter.toLowerCase();

_.where(user_filters, {[selected_filter]: filters});
```